# Regex Lookahead and Lookbehinds: followed by this or that

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regular expression that checks ahead to make sure there is either a white space character OR an opening parentheses after the words I'm searching for.
Also, I want it to look back and make sure it is preceded by either a non-Word (`\W`) or nothing at all (i.e. it is the beginning of the statement).

So far I have,

```
"(\\W?)(" + words.toString() + ")(\\s | \\()"
```

However, this also matches the stuff at either ends - I want this pattern to match ONLY the word itself - not the stuff around it.

I'm using Java flavor Regex.

Comment: If that regex matches a string it will have 4 [groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html).  The first will be the whole string, the 3rd will be the word you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged your question yourself, you need [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```java
String regex = "(?<=\\W|^)(" + Pattern.quote(words.toString()) + ")(?= |[(])"
```

- `(?<=X)` means *"preceded by X"*
- `(?<!=X)` means *"**not** preceded by X"*
- `(?=X)` means *"followed by X"*
- `(?!=X)` means *"**not** followed by X"*

Comment: Always use `Pattern.quote()` when you insert some plain string into a regex. And the `(?<=\\W|^)` can be shorten to `(?!\w)`. Also note that the `(?= |[(])` should be `(?= | [(])`

Comment: @nhahtdh Can you give an example with `Pattern.quote()`? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Could you provide the output of `words.toString()`?

Comment: Just check the documentation, `Pattern.quote(String)`. It will escape meta characters in the string before inserting it into the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

What about the word itself: will it always start with a word character (i.e., one that matches `\w`)?  If so, you can use a word boundary for the leading condition.

```
"\\b" + theWord + "(?=[\\s(])"
```

Otherwise, you can use a negative lookbehind:

```
"(?<!\\w)" + theWord + "(?=[\\s(])"
```

I'm assuming the word is either quoted like so:

```
String theWord = Pattern.quote(words.toString());
```

...or doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a group to be captured by the matching, you can use the special construct `(?:X)`

So, in your case:

```
"(?:\\W?)(" + words.toString() + ")(?:\\s | \\()"
```

You will only have two groups then, `group(0)` for the whole string and `group(1)` for the word you are looking for.

Comment: I believe the question isn't about *capturing* but *matching*: `(?:)` won't capture the group but it will be still matched.

Comment: This is a confusion of vocabulary. The OP wants to matches a word preceded by some construct C1 and followed by some construct C2, and only get the word in between. He can do that by either using lookaround as in your answer, or by matching the whole thing and getting the bit he wants as in mine. The result will be the same, and I think the OP question is about getting the data, not how to use a particular technique, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: @CyrilleKa You are correct; I just want to pull the data that I need and if the best way is not using lookarounds that's great too. However, your answer is not working for me...

Comment: You'll have to tell us more about how it is not working. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for example, and tell us what you expect and what you obtain.

Comment: Well I'm creating a `String` called `regex`, using yours from above with the words inside being `hello|goodbye`. I'm passing it as a parameter here: `Pattern.compile(regex)` then I'm creating a matcher by `pattern.matcher("hello yo and BIGhello and have a goodbye")`. When I run a while loop with `matcher.find()`, it doesn't find anything.

Comment: `(?:\W?)` will match a non-word character if there is one, but it won't *prevent* a match if there's a word character there.  And in the other group, you need to remove those spaces (i.e., `(?:\s|\()` - but you might as well compress that to `[\s(]`, like I did in my answer).